# django test RequestFactory does not include request.user

Tags: django, unit-testing, testing, request, testcase

Whenever I use the requestFactory during testing like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.client import RequestFactory
from django.test.client import Client
import nose.tools as nt

class TestSomeTestCaseWithUser(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        # Every test needs access to the request factory.
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        self.client = Client()
        self.user_foo = User.objects.create_user('foo', 'foo@bar.com', 'bar')

    def tearDown(self):
        # Delete those objects that are saved in setup
        self.user_foo.delete()

    def test_request_user(self):
        self.client.login( username='foo', password='bar')
        request = self.factory.post('/my/url/', {"somedata": "data"})
        nt.assert_equal(request.user,self.user_foo)
```

on everything I try with request.user:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'user'
```

this won't work, so I Added a workaround:

```
def test_request_user(self):
    # Create an instance of a GET request.
    self.client.login( username='foo', password='bar')
    request = self.factory.post('/my/url/', {"somedata": "data"})
    # a little workaround, because factory does not add the logged in user
    request.user = self.user_foo
    nt.assert_equal(request.user,self.user_foo)
```

I use request.user a lot in my code... so also in the things I want to (unit)test...

Thanks to this question and answer I found out you need to add the user to the request manually: [How to access request.user while testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094727/why-does-a-context-processor-in-django-1-4-raise-attributeerror-when-trying-to-a) and I added this as a workaround.

My questions are:

- Why is this?
- It feels like a bug in the request factory, is it? (so is it a workaround, or just an undocumented feature)
- Or am I doing something else wrong? (combination of test client and factory)
- Is there a better way to test with logged on users in a request?

I tried this as well: same issue

```
    response = self.client.post("/my/url/")
    request = response.request
```

By the way, this answer: [Accessing the request.user object when testing Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448038/accessing-the-request-user-object-when-testing-django) suggests to use

```
response.context['user']
```

in stead of

```
request.user
```

But in my code this is not the case, and as far as I know request.user is quit normal to use, and to explain my problem, i put the request.user in a test... in my real life, it's not in the tests... it's in the code I want to test.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

sorry... it seems it is a documented feature...

however, it would have been nice to give a better example.

see [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/advanced/#django.test.RequestFactory).

there it is in the third list item:

> It does not support middleware. Session and authentication attributes
>   must be supplied by the test itself if required for the view to
>   function properly.

however... this seem contradictional with the first sentences:

> The RequestFactory shares the same API as the test client. However,
>   instead of behaving like a browser, the RequestFactory provides a way
>   to generate a request instance that can be used as the first argument
>   to any view. This means you can test a view function the same way as
>   you would test any other function

especialy **the same way**

Not sure if I should remove this question.... solving this problem took me a lot of time... than understanding my workaround also...

So I suppose somebody can use this as well..

and I just added a documentation extending request: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20609

Comment: This is now documented appropriately from 1.5 onwards: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/testing/advanced/#module-django.test.client

Comment: Adding updated link since this other one for v1.5 no longer works. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/advanced/#module-django.test.client.